# Navigating to Opportunity related Activities List in Aura

Tags: related-list, lightning-aura-components

Trying to use force:navigateToRelatedList to navigate to an opportunitys' related activity list on a click event within an aura/lightning component.

```
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToRelatedList");
        evt.setParams({parentRecordId: ?????????});
        evt.fire();
```

I am stuck on what to send through as parameters to the event.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use force:navigateToRelatedList; fill in the following parameters

```
evt.setParams({parentRecordId: oppid, relatedListId: 'OpenActivities'});
```